# I'm having trouble displaying child pages using Gridsome and Directus

Tags: vue.js, directus, gridsome

Thanks for reading!

I am trying to display child pages in my Gridsome Directus project.

I have a Shop.vue template in the template directory.

I am using `@pienter/gridsome-source-directus` and have tried gridsome-source-directus.

The code below is what I've added in. I can't find anything online so far to help solve the problem and I'm not seeing anything in the docs that help me out.

Some of gridsome.config.js

```
`module.exports = {
    templates: {
        Shop: [
            {
                path: '/shop/:id',
                component: 'templates/Shop.vue'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        use: '@pienter/gridsome-source-directus',
        options: {
            routes: {
            shop: '/shop/:slug',
        },
    },
    }`
```

```
Error: child "path" fails because ["path" is required] at vaidateOptions (C:\wamp64\www\gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\pages\validateOptions.js:20:11) at Pages._normalizeOptions (C:\wamp64\www\gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\pages\pages.js:166:21) at Pages.createPage (C:\wamp64\www\gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\pages\pages.js:83:26) at Object.createPage (C:\wamp64\www\gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\pages\utils.js:33:20) at VueTemplates.createNodePage (C:\wamp64\www\sites\gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\plugins\vue-templates\index.js:85:23) at contentType.collection.find.forEach.node (C:\wamp64\www\gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\plugins\vue-templates\index.js:53:12) at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at VueTemplates.createTemplate (C:\wamp64\www\gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\plugins\vue-templates\index.js:52:35) at VueTemplates.createTemplates (C:\wamp64\www\gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\plugins\vue-templates\index.js:30:12) at <anonymous> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: I also have:  templates: {
    Shop: [
      {
        path: '/shop/:id',
        component: 'templates/Shop.vue'
      }
    ]
  },

Answer (score 0):

Add a field "path" to each collection of that value. How strange.